# Trouble understanding C# reference "new"

Tags: c#

```
Point point = new Point(X,Y,Z);
point = new Point(2*X, 2*Y, 2*Z);
```

Point is a reference from an external library and assuming X,Y,Z have a random initial value. I have trouble understanding what is going on between the 2 lines of code.

Comment: What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: I highly doubt that they are random values, It looks like Point doesn't have a `*` operator and is creating a new point that has been scaled.

Answer (score 3):

On the second call to new, you are allocating memory to a new object of type Point and overwriting the old value of the point variable with a pointer to the new allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

The first line is creating a new `Point` object with the three values, and storing in in the `point` variable.
The 2nd line is creating a new `Point` object with a different set of values, and also storing it in the `point` variable, overwriting what was there.